# Как работает рекурсия на примере данного JS кода?

Tags: javascript

Как работает finalPermutations?

(Через какие шаги проходит функция в процессе выполнения?)

```
function permutations(string) {
  if (string.length <= 1) {
    return [string];
  }
  
  let finalPermutations = permutations(string.substring(1))
    .reduce((acc, p) => {
      let charList = p.split('');
      for (let i = 0; i <= charList.length; i++) {
        let newPermutation = charList.slice(0, i)
                              .concat([string[0]])
                              .concat(charList.slice(i))
                              .join('');
        if (!acc.includes(newPermutation)) {
          acc.push(newPermutation);
        } 
      }
      return acc;      
  },[]);
  return finalPermutations;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я попытаюсь объяснить, но если Вы всё равно не поймёте, настоятельно советую обратиться к учебнику и внимательно прочитать [раздел про рекурсию](https://learn.javascript.ru/recursion).

Предположим у нас происходит вызов: `permutations('123');`

Условие...

```
if (string.length <= 1) {
    return [string];
  }
```

оказывается ложным и мы попадаем на следующую строку `let finalPermutations = permutations(string.substring(1))`, гду функция вызывает саму себя по факту в следующем виде `let finalPermutations = permutations('23')`. Происходит первый шаг рекурсии.

Далее происходит всё тоже самое, где функция вызывается вот так: `let finalPermutations = permutations('3')`. И в этом вызове мы достигаем базы рекурсии, т.е. того момента, когда функции больше не нужно вызывать саму себя. Она попадает внуть условия, которое по факту на данный момент выглядет так:

```
  if ('3'.length <= 1) {
    return ['3'];
  }
```

Теперь мы движемся назад по рекурсии. Внутри вызова `permutations('23')` база ркурсии превращает вот этот вызов `let finalPermutations = permutations('3').reduce((acc, p) => ...)`, конкретно вот в это: `let finalPermutations = ['3'].reduce((acc, p) => ...)`.

Далее уже начинает отрабатывать колбэек редюсера, который по завершению вырнёт в следующий верхний уровень рекурсии массив: ['23, '32'].

Так как следующий верхний уровень рекусрии является точкой входа в рекурсию вообще, то конечный результатом функции будет массив: ['123', '213', '231', '132', '312', '321'].

Вот всё тоже самое, что я попытался объяснить, только в виде схемы:

```
                    шаг рекурсии                         база рекурсии
premutations('123') ------------> premutations('23') --> premutations('3')
                                                                |
                                                         результат базы рек.        
                                    ['3'].reduce()  <--    ['3']
                                        |
                                здесь мы принимаем
                                результат базы рекурсии
                                и начинаем отрабатывать
                                дальше по функции, и получаем
                                         |
        ['23', '32'].reduce()  <-- ['23', '32']
                 |
             Конечный результат.
       ['123', '213', '231', '132', '312', '321']
```

P.S.
Если Вы не понимаете как мы получаем тот или иной результат после завершения метода `reduce`, то здесь рекомендую внимательно прочитать про каждый метод маcсива или строки, который в нём используется, и самостоятельно проследить каждый шаг внутри цикла.

Comment: Большое спасибо